# Calculating a certain probability in a Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $N(\cdot)$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\mu$. I want to compute the following probability:

$$
P(\{N((1,3]) > 0\}\cap \{N((2,4]) > 0\})
$$

I tried to split the involved intervals in half so as to achieve some sort of independence between the involved random variables, but I did not succeed. I also tried computing

$$
P(\{N((1,3]) = 0\}\cup \{N((2,4]) = 0\})
$$

but that did not yield any helpful results either. Any suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well: $$\mathsf P((A\cup B)\cap(B\cup C)) = \mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement\cap C)$$

---

And $(N_{(1;3]}{>}0)\cap( N_{(2;4]}{>}0)$ if and only if $(N_{(0;2]}{>}0\cup N_{(2;3]}{>}0)\cap (N_{(2;3]}{>}0\cup N_{(3;4]}{>}0)$.

Therefore:

> $$\mathsf P(N_{(1;3]}{>}0\cap N_{(2;4]}{>}0)~=~\mathsf P(N_{(2;3]}{>}0)+\mathsf P(N_{(1;2]}{>}0)\,\mathsf P(N_{(2;3]}{=}0)\,\mathsf P(N_{(3;4]}{>}0)$$

Comment: Beautiful and concise!